# Spring Boot multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException while sending formData via POST request in Angular

Tags: spring, angular, rest, spring-boot

I tried everything, and I am constantly getting this error from Spring Boot

> Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: **org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException**: Required request part '**file**' is not present

This is my Angular code. **NOTE**: I am using **Http** (**not HttpClient**) for my POST request.

```
updateUserProfilePicViaHttp(userId: number, imageFile: any) {

    let headers: Headers = new Headers()
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data;boundary=imageUpload');

    let formData: FormData = new FormData()
    formData.append('file', imageFile, imageFile.name)

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + `user/${userId}/profile_pic`, formData, { headers: headers })

}
```

This is my Spring Boot code

```
@RequestMapping(value="/{userId}/profile_pic",
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<User> uploadProfilePic(@PathVariable("userId") Integer id, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                                   RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){

    IUserDao userDao = (IUserDao) getDao();
    User user = null;

    try {
        user = userDao.saveAndUpdateProfilePic(id, file.getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if( user != null)
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    else
        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);


}
```

I think that there is something wrong with my Angular code, because when I send an image via Postman everything works fine!

Postman image:
[image]

Thanks!

**EDIT**: For some reason I tried replacing `@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file` with `@RequestParam MultipartFile file` in my function.
Still getting the same error

It seems that when Spring says

> Required request part 'file' is not present

It associates name 'file' with reference name of `MultiPartFile file` in my Spring boot function, not with `@RequestParam('file')`.

**EDIT2**: I listened to Ravat and modified my code a little bit.

**How I got imageFile?**

**Explanation:**
`@ViewChild('fileInput') myFile: ElementRef` reference from `<input type="file" #fileInput>`

This is what is imageFile in my Angular function.
`imageFile = this.myFile.nativeElement.files[0]`

But still, same error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 6 hours of googling and explaining to Duck Overflow what is the problem, I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11819).

And I just removed my header

`headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data;boundary=imageUpload');`

**Final code**

```
updateUserProfilePicViaHttp(userId: number, imageFile: any) {

    let formData: FormData = new FormData()

    formData.append('file', imageFile, imageFile.name)

    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + `user/${userId}/profile_pic`, formData)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Issue is in following code code

```
updateUserProfilePicViaHttp(userId: number, image: string) {...}
```

I don't know about angular, here you are sending string in an image variable

that definitely won't work because it needs to be a file.

Comment: Tried other ways with manipulating files, still getting the same error.

Comment: http://www.kaushikbaruah.com/posts/send-image-in-form-data-angular/, can you once go through this link, this may help you to find out your root cause

Comment: doesn't help, and that is AngularJS